# Godot Light2D exposes tilemap border lines

Tags: godot

So I've been using Light2D for godot for my TileMap 2D game. Only problem is it exposes the tiles borders. See. Image Below.

[image: Areas around the light look normal but witthin the Light2D area it exposes the borders of the tiles]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here because they are seeing this issue on an isometric TileMap, select the TileMap in the Scene panel, expand the Cell category in the Inspector, and make sure that Y Sort is ticked. This will resolve the overlapping lighting issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you set your tiles overlap.