# Godot Engine: Light2d combined with overlapping tiles mixing underneath part

Tags: godot

Bug or do is miss something?

My Godot project has a Tilemap and a Light2d.
Some tiles do overlap (e.g. when using isometric tiles this is common).
As light texture I'm a using a radial gradient.
When the Light2d Energy is set for e.g. 0.5 the overlapping part of the underneath tile "shines through" (is mixed using the set mode). Setting "Y Sort" to "On" for the Tilemap does change the behavior a little bit, but it's still incorrect.
[image: Y Sort on]
[image: Y Sort on]
Light-Settings:
[image: Light settings]

I think this issue is the same as [godot-light2d-exposes-tilemap-border-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216089/godot-light2d-exposes-tilemap-border-lines)[Godot Light2D exposes tilemap border lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216089/godot-light2d-exposes-tilemap-border-lines)
But: This is an 2 years old issue (!?)

**Update** It's an issue now:
See: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/50439

Comment: It works for me with Cell Y Sort. I tried searching the repository issues, but I could not find a bug report on this. I suggest making a minimal project that showcases the problem and opening an issue.

Comment: I will do. Thx.